# How to decrypt PGP files in aws S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sftp, pgp

Client is providing huge PGP encrypted gz files (around 20 GB) in SFTP. They are also providing private key(.priv.asc) in our EC2 local. Now my requirement is to transfer the file from SFTP to aws s3 using AWS Transfer for SFTP service. After loading the file in aws s3, i want to decrypt and then unzip the file before processing it.

Can someone please help me, how to decrypt the PGP file with the key present in EC2 local.

Note : One approach is to load the data in EC2 first, then decrypt and unzip it and then load the data in S3. I tried this process. But after unzipping, file size is becoming around 80GB and it is taking too much time to upload into s3. I want to avoid this approach.